# VirtualBox network device not found

Tags: virtualbox

I have ubuntu os installed in oracle virtualbox. The network interface is not working after I changed the mac address of it in the virtualbox settings and I'm getting following error.

> Blockquote

eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

> Blockquote

any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. disable nic 1 and create new
   or 2. shutdown guest os, edit ~/.VirtualBox/Machines/GUESTNAME/GUESTNAME.xml, section Hardware Adapter NN

   > ```
   >     <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true"
   > ```
   >
   > MACAddress="080027B7E4E9" cable="true"
   >   speed="0" type="Am79C973">
   >             
   >           
   >   or 3. if you have snapshot, rollback to early snapshot

Comment: I added net interface eth0 again but ip address is not assigned to this interface. I even tried 'dhclient', it kept on requesting ip but finally it didn't.

Comment: Can't I do host to guest networking with NAT enabled. Because I long ago tried virtualbox network mode to Bridged and I could do host to guest networking but I couldn't access internet on the guest!

Comment: It's ok if have any tweak to access internet with bridged mode so that I can have both host-guest networking and internet.